# android library project and Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-library

I'm developing an Android SDK library. In this library I've declared and used some Activities. Now I've tried to include the library in an application but I've noticed that I must declare all the library activities in the app. This is a very bad thing because in the library, I've included a lot of activities and the developer has to copy all the activities in his own app. Is there a solutions to this?

Comment: what do you mean copy the activities to the other app?  are you talking about the manifest?  If so, Google says they intend to add manifest merging in the future but you need to copy/paste for now.  If not, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @schwiz manifestmerger.enabled=true is exist now, but we should force developers(who use my library in their apps), to set min and target SDK to our min and target sdk! (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976635/using-the-new-manifestmerger-property-in-android#21397467)

Answer (score 26):

No, this is a known limitation of the libraries at the moment.  There is a lot of discussion in the android development community of fixing this in the future, but for now it is a limitation of how they do libraries.

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryReference)

> In the manifest file of the
>   application project, you must add
>   declarations of all components that
>   the application will use that are
>   imported from a library project. For
>   example, you must declare any
>   `<activity>`, `<service>`, `<receiver>`,
>   `<provider>`, and so on, as well as
>   `<permission>`, `<uses-library>`, and
>   similar elements.

Also, excellent answer [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9ab55802c29278a3?pli=1) by Mark Murphy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Maybe i've to use Dialogs instead of activities. This could be avoid this limitation. Do you agree?

Comment: (in addition: i don't need to create a jar)

Comment: The only part of your library that will need to be in the consuming project is the declaration in the android manifest.  I'm not sure what you mean about using dialogs instead of activities.

Comment: If i use Dialogs to display user interfaces i don't need to declare them in the manifest.

Comment: Architecturally there is a significant difference between dialogs and activities. Dialogs will share much more state with the application consuming them and you'll need to setup some structured mechanism for the consuming app to invoke them. It really depends on what you're trying to do to determine if that is a viable alternative.

Answer (score 22):

**Update 1:** When using Gradle, Manifest merging is done now automatically. More details on how it works and how to resolve conflicts can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html) (thanks for the remark guy.gc)

**Original post:**

To update this thread: auto merge is now possible. You would only have to add

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

to your project.properties. [Using the new "manifestmerger" property in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976635/using-the-new-manifestmerger-property-in-android) discusses this also.

I know this is an old thread but I just stumbled upon it and want to prevent others (me included) from thinking it is not possible. This one line was totally enough in my projects to make use of Activities in the library-consuming App.

Comment: Actually manifest merging is done automatically. http://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html

If needed you can define how conflicts are resolved

Comment: Thanks for the comment @guy.gc, I will update the answer