# Broadcast Receiver in a Library Project not working

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have implemented `Broadcast Receiver` in a `library` project for checking the `Boot Completed` event , but it is not working.

Broadcast Receiver Class :

```
public class Reciever  extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
       if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
       {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Device Boot Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".Reciever"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I implemented same Receiver in another application (not library project) and it is working fine.

Comment: did you add the receiver in the manifest of the library AND the app?

Comment: have you solved this problem? @Hammad

Answer (score 1):

BroadcastReceiver cannot be defined in the library project's manifest. The hosting project always needs to declare the components.

[android library project and Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046864/android-library-project-and-activities)

Edit:
I feel this should work with latest Android studio/ gradle based projects.

Answer (score 0):

You might skipped

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

In manifest file

Comment: I added this permission

Answer (score 0):

Override the following method

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

Answer (score -1):

You should add **receive tag**  and **reboot permissions** to client application manifest file which using your library jar

Like this;

> ```
>      <receiver android:name="com.example.library.ReceiverClass"
>          <intent-filter>
>              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
>          </intent-filter>           
>      </receiver>
> ```

Comment: There is no receive tag. "reboot permission" is not required as well.