# how to access library class from another android project

Tags: android, library-project

Hi I am working with android.I had created a library project. Now I integrated it with my new app. Now how can I access the library main class to my new project ???

Comment: What is library main class?

Comment: I had created an android project and is marked as library.. now ho can I access its features in my new project after integrated it???

Answer (score 1):

Its depend on your Library project. How you have create it. Mean pure java file or you have use some other resources also.

Simply refer [official document here.](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) & Other reference link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085313/how-to-create-your-own-library-for-android-development-to-be-used-in-every-progr).

You can use that Class using importing package , Like i have one lib and i have added as lib project and i am importing that lib package as below.

```
import chintan.khetiya.android.my_custom_lib.*;
```

If you have use `<activity>, <service>, <receiver>, <provider>, and so on, as well as <permission>, <uses-library>,` any of these then you have to add all of these in your real project. [See For More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046864/android-library-project-and-activities)

Comment: I had created an android project and is marked as library.. now ho can I access its features in my new project after integrated it???

Comment: As i have already told you , like in my lib `DBHelper.java` is a class  now if i want to use this then first add that lib project in my new project and use your class they will ask about importing package.That's it

Comment: is it possible to access oncreate actions in my library project from my new app??

Comment: for that you have to make an Interface and that will call your event whenever you want check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046864/android-library-project-and-activities check this also

Answer (score 0):

If you use eclipse;

Right click your project in "Project Explorer" view, than open window select "Android" tab left side. At right side bottom container you will see "add button" click and select project.

""Your library and project in same workspace.""

Comment: I already done it.I had used the code startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class)); to access the library project oncreate in my onclick action of a button in new project but it force closed

Comment: You will declare your manifest.xml library's activity. Because library project have not context.

Comment: What's your log cat detail? Could you post it?